# How can i read a digital pins value from another device?

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I on a raspberry pi 4 (device 2) and am trying to read a digital data pin from another raspberry pi (device 1) but the value always reads as 0. What do i need to do to make this work? I already tried connecting a ground pin from device 1 to device 2 to get electricity to flow but that did not change anything.

Device 1 (Raspberry pi pico - MicroPython):

```
from machine import Pin
import time

dataAvailablePin = Pin(0, Pin.OUT)

while True:
  dataAvailablePin.value(0 if dataAvailablePin.value() == 1 else 1)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Device 2 (Raspberry pi 4 - Ubuntu 20.04 with python3):

```
import wiringpi
import time

PIN_DATA_AVAILABLE = 17

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi.pinMode(PIN_DATA_AVAILABLE, 0)

while True:
  print(wiringpi.digitalRead(PIN_DATA_AVAILABLE))
  time.sleep(.2)
```

I get the same result when using RPi.GPIO instead of wiringpi on device 2:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

PIN_DATA_AVAILABLE = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PIN_DATA_AVAILABLE, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while True:
    print(GPIO.input(PIN_DATA_AVAILABLE))
    time.sleep(.2)
```

(*1) Measuring voltage from device 1 gpio pin 0 with a ground pin from device 1 shows 3.3v and 0v alternating each second as expected.

(*2) Measuring voltage from device 1 gpio pin 0 with a ground pin from device 2 shows 0v.

Sorry for the bad diagram. Btw what is a good tool to draw some random wiring instead of paint.net? :)

[image]
[image]

EDIT: The problem was a faulty connection, after fixing it, it works fine.

Comment: Use ANYTHING except `WiringPi` (`RPi.GPIO` or `pigpio`, for example). WiringPi has a default pin numbering scheme that doesn't use BCM numbering.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip, i will look into that. I am pretty sure i have the correct pin though as i have previously tested it by enabling it and disabling it every second and measuring the voltage. Basically the same thing i am doing for the device 1 now.

Comment: I updated my question with a ´RPi.GPIO´code sample

Comment: What on Earth do you think `dataAvailablePin.value(0 if dataAvailablePin.value() == 1 else 1)` is doing?

Comment: @joan According to my console output it turns the pin on when it´s off and off when it´s on, what´s the problem with it?

Comment: Post a photo of your wiring, i assume you have 2 wires connected but it's not clear. Pico GND -> Pi GND and Pico GP0 -> Pi GPIO17 ?

Comment: You should also pull the Pi input down, add another parameter ",pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)". What gets printer on the Pi?

Comment: @CoderMike I added a picture, and adding the parameter didn't change anything, all that gets printed is '0'.

Comment: It sounds like the ground between the two devices is faulty.  Try another jumper wire.

Comment: Your Pico pin header is not soldered! It must be soldered for reliable connections!

Comment: I got it to work, it was a faulty connection, thanks for the help, btw what is incomprehensible and complex in detail?